# Azure security - how to collect audit failure log

Tags: azure, security, azure-active-directory, cloud

how would you go about collecting all the audit failure data from the security log of a virtual machine to an Azure Storage account

Comment: Could you please specify your query? For instance, which way(rest api,sdk or powershell) do you want to get this? And which way you want to use on Azure VM to access Azure storage account ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are mainly interested in logon failures to your virtual machines. If this is the case, you can enable Standard tier Security Center and [create a Log Analytics workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-create-workspace).

[image]

After you have deployed the Log Analytics workspace you can [connect it to your VM and collect event log data](https://azurealan.ie/2019/11/12/monitoring-failed-login-attempts-to-your-azure-virtual-machines/). Go to Logs under the Monitoring section of your VM and assign it to your Log Analytics workspace.